# How to view I/O bridge in linux?

Tags: linux, drivers, pci-express, pci

My laptop lenovo legion r7000 2020 env (with amd r7 4800h cpu):

```bash
$ uname -a
Linux CzgArch 6.3.8-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed, 14 Jun 2023 20:10:31 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

Recently when I searched for NUMA, I found this [Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/888430/numa-cpu-numbering-in-linux?newreg=e3e9cfe5874c45348b67eb4fc40d1dc4), then I get the image by `lstopo --of png > server.png`: [cpu_arch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpl1I.png) (I don't have enough reputation. So you should open the link to view the image. Sorry. This is my first question.)

Then I viewed the `man lstopo` and found the `2.0` on the line between package and PCI 01:00:0 is **I/O bridge**. Does it mean the same as [PCI/PCI bridge](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.os.linux.hardware/c/kmXrWGz2LrI?pli=1)?

I used the [`lspci -tvv`](https://superuser.com/questions/1375202/how-to-understand-lspci-tree-format) to view the bridge, but not found related infos:

```bash
$ lspci -tvv                   
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
           +-00.2  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
           +-01.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
           +-01.1-[01]--+-00.0  NVIDIA Corporation TU117M
           |            \-00.1  NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa
...
```

Here `[01]--+-00.0` corresponds to the above image `01:00.0` device.

Q: how to interpret bridge strings like `2.0` in the above image?

Comment: please be more specific if it is a business related question in a business environment

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found the referenced Q&A in serverfault, so I posted here. It isn't in one business environment. I will update my question with some information about my laptop. Hope that will help you understand my question.